# Как организовать подсчет итоговых параметров персонажа из экипировки в RPG?

Tags: delphi, классы, разработка-игр, pascal

Возможно ли создать метод, автоматически ищущий поле класса по имени этого поля. Делаю RPG. Пример: персонаж одевает вещь, она дает прибавку урона и здоровья(тут все просто), но у другой вещи другой набор параметров, скажем урон и защита, прошлый метод уже не подходит. В итоге писать кучу методов под все случаи жизни?! Код абсолютно не гибкий(

Comment: Собственно, ООП для такого и придумали - хорошо продумываете, что вам понадобится, создаете базовый класс "вещь" с виртуальными методами отрисовать, надеть, снять - и что еще нужно для всех вещей. Потом создаете производные классы, перекрывая указанные методы, в реализации которых делаете конкретные действия для данного класса.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ! Я вроде и понимаю то что вы сказали, +/- так и собирался это делать, но ответа на свой вопрос все равно не вижу. Как персонаж при одевании вещи будет понимать какой набор характеристик есть у вещи и каким полям у себя он должен их добавить?

Comment: У каждой вещи - список свойств в виде текста или словаря.

Answer (score 3):

Вы как-то не с той стороны заходите. В общем случае, вам может быть проще и удобнее другой подход.

0. Делаете список параметров (можно enum)
1. Делаете базовый класс (или рекорд) для вещи
2. Для персонажа, делаете массив или список надетых вещей
3. Для персонажа, делаете набор параметров (урон, здоровье, защита и т.п.)
4. Теперь итерируетесь по вещам, чтобы каждая сказала какое у нее значение параметра
5. Записываете результирующие значения персонажа

---

Пример, есть 3 параметра и 2 вещи.

```
TPersParameter = (ppDamage, ppHealth, ppDefense);
```

```
TEquipmentType = (etHelmet, etArmor, etBoots, etWeapon1Hand, etShield, ...);

TEquipment = class
  ParamValues: array [TPersParameter] of Single;
```

```
TPerson = class
  Equipment: array [TEquipmentType] of TEquipment;
  function GetTotalParamValue(aParam: TPersParameter): Single;
```

```
function GetTotalParamValue(aParam: TPersParameter): Single;
var
  I: TEquipmentType;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for I := Low(TEquipmentType) to High(TEquipmentType) do
  if Equipment[I] <> nil then
    Result := Result + Equipment[I].ParamValues[aParam];
```

---

Соответственно, при развитии системы, как принято в классических RPG, вы можете поменяете `ppDamage` на 2 разных параметра - `ppDamageMin` и `ppDamageMax`, чтобы собирать их по отдельности. А также, сделать разделение на простые значения, и проценты. Например `ppHealthBase` и `ppHealthPercent`, и будете считать итог как:

```
Result := GetTotalParamValue(ppHealthBase) * (1 + GetTotalParamValue(ppHealthPercent));
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Вы меня наставили на путь истинный. А то уже неделю тыкаюсь мыкаюсь с этими переменными и кучу теории перелопатил, а оказывается нужно просто работать со списками)

Comment: @AbeNSouR если будут еще вопросы - можете написать мне в Дискорд (ник в моем профиле). Геймдев на Делфи это моя тема ))

Comment: Благодарю. Если опять упрусь в непробиваемый потолок напишу) Может у вас есть на заметке что почитать про разработку рпг, где реально можно подчерпнуть практической годноты. А то в интернете все абстракциями поясняют, а хочется еще понять как примерно реализуют это риал-прогеры)

Comment: @AbeNSouR конкретики нет - слишком обширная тема. Самое главное я бы выделил KISS, YAGNI и DRY, а все остальное приложится ))

Comment: Добро. Думаю тема закрыта. Раз такое дело, у меня есть еще одна плохо реализованная структура, могу вам задать вопрос в дискорде?

Comment: @AbeNSouR если ответ вам помог - нажмите стрелку вверх. Если ответ решает вопрос - нажмите галку. Правила площадки ruSO )